# Morgan Logger with Express.js only logging failed requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, express

I'm using Morgan with Express.js and I think I have a problem with my middleware because Morgan is only logging requests returning error 302 (redirected), which is occurring when my middleware catches an error and redirects to its error page.

I'm fairly new to Express.js an all the middleware jazz so I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```js
var http = require('http')
    , express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , logger = require('morgan');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(logger());

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8888);

// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).redirect('/error/404.html');
});

// Handle 500
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).redirect('/error/500.html');
});
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting instead of rendering/sending the relevant html error file?  Something like `res.status(500).render('505_template');` or such?

Comment: [I've tried that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210130/error-404-page-not-working-with-express) :/ Do you know what my problem is? The argument for `app.render()` is a path to a .html file, right? @MattBakaitis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of 'getting it to work', the code below will do this for 404's.

I didn't answer anything regarding other response codes, leaving that to you.  :)

**Getting it to work**

A summary of what I changed:

1. I removed the dependency on `'http'` and the `var server = http.createServer(app);` because those aren't really needed
2. I moved `app.listen` to the end...so it listens after all express configuration is complete.
3. I used the `.sendfile()` method instead of `.redirect()` since we're just sending status stuff around

This worked on my system. If you have questions about the code or issues with it leave a comment and I will help as I am able...but I can't promise miracles in comments.  :)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var logger = require('morgan');

// edited, moving `app.use(logger());` first so it can log everything...    
app.use(logger());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).sendfile('./error/404.html');
});

app.listen(8888);
```

**A quick aside:**

My guess is that some of the issues in your code are based upon the fact that many express tutorials/guides were written for v.3.x but the changes in v.4.x are substantial enough that it's not super-easy to figure out what might still work and what doesn't.

For example, you'd only be using `morgan` with an express v.4.x app but several things in your code look like they came from a v.3.x app/example/tutorial.  When I started, the same stuff was happening as express moved from v.2.x to v.3.x...so yeah. I feel your pain.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your thoughtful and complete answer!  However, although the error pages work now, that didn't help with the logger issue.  It still only logs requests with error 404 (presumably, maybe other errors).  Did that part work on your system? @MattBakaitis

Comment: Sorry...the order of middleware matters.  I've edited the answer.  The logger needs to be first.

Comment: Not to nag, but if it answered the question, I would appreciate getting credit for the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Oops, sorry! Forgot :P @MattBakaitis